# SD card reader drivers problem

Tags: drivers, sd-card

I am new to Linux, and facing a problem running Ubuntu 18.04.
I tried to install proprietary drivers for my SD card, but it is still not recognized in Ubuntu.

Step by step guidance for compilation and installation of the needed drivers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is `lspci -v` result:

```
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
Memory at f7900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

Sorry for not replying at time, I was in trip. And many thanks for your kind help. here is what I get after     ~$ sudo dmesg | tail -n 50

```
dusty@dusty-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ sudo dmesg | tail -n 50
[29339.385609] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[29349.061281] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29350.107613] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29351.125995] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29352.169015] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29353.214446] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29366.761743] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29389.321948] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29434.827286] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29464.270447] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[29589.154194] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[29591.816396] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29627.029781] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29628.042071] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29688.294931] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29689.337801] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29690.389711] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29691.440618] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29707.051882] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29714.038022] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[29742.084483] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29779.012250] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29838.921841] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[29963.849425] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[29989.033049] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[29990.199752] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30024.047537] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30025.108447] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30026.134421] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30027.163400] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30028.187354] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30029.228006] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30088.737416] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[30162.033332] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30163.068038] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30213.621145] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[30228.707802] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30240.986477] rtsx_pci_sdmmc rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0: no support for card's volts
[30240.986479] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[30241.548761] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[30242.692761] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[30243.840757] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[30267.368765] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30268.367692] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30290.914360] rtsx_pci_sdmmc rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0: no support for card's volts
[30290.914362] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[30323.029859] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30331.066949] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:bc:20:10:ad:87:cc:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:be20:10ff:fead:87cc DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=81 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=33398 DPT=19133 LEN=41 
[30338.504947] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[30463.388830] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:ab:1b:c5:4c:cb:08:00 SRC=192.168.3.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

And what I get after sudo lsblk -f

```
dusty@dusty-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/
loop1  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop2  squashf                                            /snap/vlc/365
loop3  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-characters
loop4  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-system-mon
loop5  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-calculator
loop6  squashf                                            /snap/core/4486
loop7  squashf                                            /snap/core/4830
loop8  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-calculator
loop9  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-system-mon
loop10 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-characters
loop11 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop12 squashf                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/
sda                                                       
├─sda1 vfat          7E2E-28DD                            /boot/efi
└─sda2 ext4          5035a5ec-53b8-49c5-a24b-c84dd1e291c8 /
sr0                                                       
dusty@dusty-Lenovo-B50-30:~$
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? Did you properly clean up afterward?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Looks like your computer recognises the device and loads a driver for it from the kernel module `rtsx_pci`. Could you please [edit] your question to describe what you expect to happen when you connect a memory card to the card reader and what *exactly* happens instead? Please also include the output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` (about 10–30 seconds after connection) and `sudo lsblk -f` in your question? Thanks.